# Safe to Delete Keynote Cache under /Library/Container/com.apple.iWork.Keynote/Data/Library/Caches

Tags: keynote, iwork

While the question "is it safe to delete /Library/Caches" is commonly seen, OSX also has another path for storing caches (not sym link). Keynote has another cache stored at /Library/Container/com.apple.iWork.Keynote/Data/Library/Caches. In particular, a subfolder named DocumentCaches store a some of my slides created in keynotes.

Is it safe to delete this folder?

Answer (score 1):

Cache is cache. Deleting it is safe. It's recommended to have all applications involved closed tho. Tools like Onyx are mostly the best way to just do a periodic cleansing every now and then.

If you just intend to delete that cache; no worries. Just close Keynote and remove the caches. You might want to remove the app states for that app too if this is a matter of something behaving weird in while working in it.